# Where is Nietzsche's Antichrist last part (Law against Christianity)?

Tags: reference-request, nietzsche, christianity

I was looking for a sentence in the last part of Nietzsche's The Antichrist (a part called "Law against Christianity"), which comes after the chapter 62. To my surprise, the vast majority of "full-texts" I found on the Web lack that last part! For instance:

[Project Gutenberg EBook](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/19322/pg19322.txt)

[Project Gutenberg EBook @ archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/theantichrist19322gut/19322.txt)

[H.L. Mencken translation @ The American Mercury](http://theamericanmercury.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/antichrist-friedrich-nietzsche-translated-h-l-mencken.pdf)

[The University of Adelaide Library](https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/n/nietzsche/friedrich/antichrist/complete.html)

[Walter Kaufmann translation @ Dave's Fringe](http://fringe.davesource.com/Fringe/Religion/Nietzsche-The-Anti-Christ/)

[Nietzsche's Features @ holtof.com](http://nietzsche.holtof.com/Nietzsche_the_antichrist/the_antichrist.htm)

[Lexido (The Full and Free Nietzsche Portal) (there's nothing on Next Section after chapter 62)](http://www.lexido.com/EBOOK_TEXTS/THE_ANTICHRIST_.aspx?S=62)

[German version by University of Toronto](https://germanenherz.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/nietzscheantichrist.pdf)

[German version @ bare-jesus.net](http://www.bare-jesus.net/nietzsche/wortlaut.pdf)

Only a few versions have the last part:

[Cambridge Texts in the History of Philosophy @ abundanthope.org](http://krishnamurti.abundanthope.org/index_htm_files/The-Anti-Christ-Ecce-Homo-Twilight-Of-The-Idols-And-Other-Writings-by-Nietzsche.pdf)

[Cambridge Texts in the History of Philosophy @ shadowsgovernment.com](http://www.shadowsgovernment.com/shadows-library/Friedrich%20Nietzsche/The%20Anti-Christ,%20Ecce%20Homo,%20Twilight%20of%20the%20Idols%20&%20Other%20Writings%20%281019%29/The%20Anti-Christ,%20Ecce%20Homo,%20Twilight%20of%20the%20Idols%20&%20Other%20Writings%20-%20Friedrich%20Nietzsche.pdf)

[German version @ archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/Nietzsche-Friedrich-Der-Antichrist/NietzscheFriedrich-DerAntichrist189570S.Text_djvu.txt)

Of course some of these versions stem from the same one. The question is: why the vast majority don't show the last part? Didn't it appear in the first edition, or in a later edition? Was it supressed by someone ideologically biased (maybe his sister)? All this together? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Antichrist_%28book%29#Suppressed_passages) says it's been supressed, but lacks references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comment by [Jeremiah Bowden](https://www.academia.edu/621253/Nietzsche_and_the_New_Atheists?auto=download) at the very least offers a curt explanation of its obscurity (page 10):

> Nietzsche is especially vehement in his denunciation of the Christian view of sex...
>
> Moreover, in his "Law Against Christianity", **a piece that was eliminated from numerous editions of The Antichrist because of its virulence**, Nietzsche proposes that, "The preacher of chastity is a public incitement to anti-nature. Contempt for sexuality, making it unclean with the concept of 'uncleanliness‘, these are the real sins against the holy spirit of life."

Fortunately the citation notes indicate which edition of "The Anti-Christ" the quote came from:

Friedrich [Nietzsche](https://youtu.be/MFUlXPX_-_E), “Law Against Christianity,” in *The Anti-Christ, Ecce Homo, Twilight of the Idols, and Other Writings* eds. Aaron Ridley and Judith Norman, trans. Judith Norman (New York: Cambridge University Press,2005), 67.

And that edition I found here:  http://krishnamurti.abundanthope.org/index_htm_files/The-Anti-Christ-Ecce-Homo-Twilight-Of-The-Idols-And-Other-Writings-by-Nietzsche.pdf

In particular the article is on page 66-67.

> Law against Christianity
>
> Given on the Day of Salvation, on the first day of the year one (-30 September 1888, according to the false calculation of time)
>
> *War to the death against vice: the vice is Christianity*
>
> *First proposition.* - Every type of anti-nature is a vice. The priest is the most vicious type of person: he *teaches* anti-nature. Priests are not to be reasoned with, they are to be locked up.
>
> *Second proposition.* - Any participation in church services is an attack on public morality. One should be harsher with Protestants than with Catholics, harsher with liberal Protestants than with orthodox ones. The criminality of being Christian increases with your proximity to science. The criminal of criminals is consequently the *philosopher.*
>
> *Third proposition.* - The execrable location where Christianity brooded over its basilisk eggs should be razed to the ground and, being the *depraved* spot on earth, it should be the horror of all posterity. Poisonous snakes should be bred on top of it.
>
> *Fourth proposition.* - The preacher of chastity is a public incitement to anti-nature. Contempt for sexuality, making it unclean with the concept of 'uncleanliness', these are the real sins against the holy spirit of life.
>
> *Fifth proposition.* - Eating at the same table as a priest ostracizes: you are excommunicated from honest society. The priest is *our* Chandala, - he should be ostracized, starved, driven into every type of desert.
>
> *Sixth proposition.* - The 'holy' history should be called by the name it deserves, the accursed history; the words 'God', 'saviour', 'redeemer', 'saint' should be used as terms of abuse, to signify criminals.
>
> *Seventh proposition.* - The rest follows from this.

Obviously tho, the work has been supressed for this:

> The criminal of criminals is consequently the *philosopher.*

;^)

Comment: Poor Nietzsche has lost completely his mind at this period. (about 10 years before his death)

Comment: @JohnAm No, he didn't. He lost his mind after that, probably after seeing how people were so stubborn to see the obvious. And still are. You probably never seen a healthy culture (like that of Amerindians, for instance), to think this way.

Comment: @Rodrigo Mental illness does not appear suddenly. Nietzsche suffered for a long time a degradation of his mental abilities. You don't "lose your mind" because "people are stubborn". Mental illness has pathological causes.

Comment: @JohnAm the chapter in question is his conclusion from the whole of The Antichrist. Which part of the whole book do you think is false?

Comment: @JohnAm The parameter you are not taking into account is the truth behind the whole of his book. And to run away from the debate is a sign that you cannot support your position.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55423/discussion-between-john-am-and-rodrigo).

Comment: Translators note: "The last page of the manuscript was left out by the publishers of the book. It was first published in 1961 by Erich E. Podach"